# Cannot find module 'rxjs/subject/BehaviorSubject'

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am using Angular 2.

When I use either of these two, my program runs well:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
```

However, I try to use the following way:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/subject/BehaviorSubject';
```

But I failed, my browser console shows:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs/subject/BehaviorSubject'

How can I use third way correctly? Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the way you configure rxjs in your main HTML file? Thanks!

Comment: @ThierryTemplier haha, same again. Actually I am using angular2-meteor, so I don't have those stuff..

Comment: I have a look at the rxjs source (`Rx.js`) and I can see the module registration: `System.register("rxjs/subject/BehaviorSubject", ...`. Any hints about the used version? ;-)

Comment: @ThierryTemplier oh, I don't know where to check my RxJS exact version.. I only know it is RxJS 5..

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
```

**rxjs 6.x**

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
```

See also

- [Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067580/property-of-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-observable/38067643#38067643)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49665105/3232832

Comment: Thanks, but now it shows: `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: BehaviorSubject is not defined`, actually I am quite confused now which way is recommended now..

Comment: One more question. Is it because the new beta version, so the import way changed? thanks

Comment: What was the last version you used? I'm not aware of related changes but it would be easy to check.

Comment: I think it is Angular2 beta 12, RxJS 5 (but not sure which beta version).

Comment: I'll check a bit later, have to leave for now.

Comment: Works the same for me in beta.12

Comment: If you are here because you are trying to use @angular/flex-layout and got errors about BehaviorSubject, try installing @angular/flex-layout@6.0.0-beta.15.  Worked for me.

Comment: rxjs 6.x looks like `import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject';`  This is where it's invaluable to have an IDE like WebStorm/PHPStorm - autocomplete so you can discover import paths like that.

Comment: rxjs 6.x looks like `import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';`, more details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49665105/3232832