# Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable

Tags: angular

I was recently using observable on my authentication token like

```
Observable.of('token');
```

But it keeps giving me above mentioned error, though i have already imported this.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Comment: import { of } from 'rxjs'; and use it like this of('token'); without Observable

Answer (score 493, accepted):

You need to import it:

**for Angular >= 6.0.0**

uses RxJS 6.0.0 [Angular Changelog 6.0.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-2018-05-03)

```ts
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

And its usage has been changed, you no longer call it off of Observable:

```ts
of('token');
```

[RxJS v5.x to v6 Update Guide - HowTo: Convert to pipe syntax](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax) which uses `of()`

**for Angular <= 5.x.xx**

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

And it's used as you have in your question

```ts
Observable.of('token');
```

Comment: i tried using this but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: but since we are using the properties of already imported object i.e Observable, do you think it's a good approach by angular2 to explicitly import different properties of already imported object?
Please enlighten me about it.

Comment: uh oh, i searched more about it. there were just some directory changes in recent rc may be. it works fine now.
`import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I found I don't need to use this statement in one of angular  projects. But in the other one, I have to import it. I don't understand the differences. Do you know the reasons?

Comment: Can't tell without more information. Perhaps you don't use observable functions that need to be imported in this project.

Comment: If you are having trouble, make sure you are importing from the OBSERVABLE directory and not the OPERATOR directory.

Comment: This is not solving the issue. I am not seeing any other solutions. Are you aware of any other options?

Comment: It did for many people. I don't know why it doesn't for you. You didn't privide any information. Perhaps it's better ti create a new question with your code and exact error and a reproduction in http://stackblitz.com

Comment: They had some breaking changes in Angular 5/6 and RxJS. It is `import { of } from 'rxjs';` and `of('token');` now. See answers in the linked duplicate-of-question.

Comment: @MA-Maddin's answer worked for me.  It's important to note not just the import statement, but also that the usage has changed. Instead of calling Observable.of(), you just call of().

Comment: not working in angular 8

Comment: not working in angular 9

Comment: Please check the Rxjs version installed, because in the official docs it's mentioned :import { of } from 'rxjs';