# How to mock a observable stream while testing angular2 components?

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-testing, angular2-observables

I am writing test cases for angular2 components.

I had created a service which uses observable stream as below:

```
import {Injectable}      from '@angular/core'
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {User} from './user.model';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  selectedUserInstance:User = new User();

  // Observable selectedUser source
  private selectedUserSource = new Subject<User>();

  // Observable selectColumn stream
  selectedUser$ = this.selectedUserSource.asObservable();

  // service command
  selectUser(user:User) {
    this.selectedUserInstance=user;
    this.selectedUserSource.next(user);
  }
}
```

Now In my component I have subscribed to this stream as :

```
getSelectedUser() {
    this.subscriptionUser = this.userService.selectedUser$.subscribe(
      selectedUser => {
        this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
      }
    );
}
```

Now in my spec.ts file, I want to mock this stream as :

```
spyOn(userService, 'selectedUser$')
        .and.returnValue(Observable.of({
            'name': 'bhushan',
            'desc': 'student'
        }));
```

But it keeps giving me following error:

> Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for selectColumn$()

is there any way to do this?

I am stuck on this issue for very long time now.

any inputs?

thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`selectedUser$` isn't a method, so you can't spy on it. Instead, if you want you can just assign it a your observable

```
rapidColumnService.selectedUser$ = Observable.of({
  'name': 'bhushan',
  'desc': 'student'
})
```

> **NOTE (UPDATE)**: see updated usage of `of` here: [Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067580/property-of-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-observable)

But honestly, if that is your complete service, I don't see why you even need to mock it. It is simple enough where using the real service probably wouldn't hurt. If you use the real service, then you can just `selectUser` whenever you want to emit something new to the component under test.

### UPDATE

Another thing you could also do is instead of using an `Observable` is to use a `Subject`. A `Subject` is also an `Observable`, but it lets you emit values, making it easier to mock values to test.

```
rapidColumnService.selectedUser$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>();
```

Then when you want to send a value

```
rapidColumnService.selectedUser$.next({
  'name': 'bhushan',
  'desc': 'student'
});
```

Depending on how you have your component set up and the subscription, you may just want to use a plain `Subject` instead of a `BehaviorSubject. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43119768/2587435) for more info.

Comment: you're GOD, saved my time +1

Comment: What should my expect statement say?

Comment: Using a subject might work for the test but provide unneeded access to fire and other methods right?

Comment: It's nicer to create a new, different BehaviorSubject and using the BehaviorSubject.asObservable() as selectedUser$ value. In this way the original type won't be changed. Similarly to the original service version.

Comment: This is not a correct answer (at least the first part). By using 'of', you create a synchronous observable, that will behave differently in tests if compared to async observable.
To correctly mock an async Observable stream you have to use scheduler like this:
 `scheduled(of(value), asapScheduler)`