# Pass data between routes in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to share data between the login page and the sign-up page. If the user tries to login and authentication fails I wish to redirect to the sign-up page with the login attempt data pre-filled. I'm trying to pass the data using a shared service, declared as provider in app.module.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {AuthenticationService} from "../../services/authentication.service";
import {SharedService} from "../../services/shared.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['login.component.scss']
})

export class PageLoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( 
                 private router: Router,
                 private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
                 private sharedService: SharedService
    ) {}


    onSubmit(data) {

        this.sharedService.setData(data);
        this.authenticationService.login(data)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                },
                error => {

                    this.router.navigate(['/sign-up']);

                });
    }
}
```

I'm using a shared service for passing the data to the sign-up page.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
    // Observable string sources
    private subject = new Subject<string>();


    setData(data) {
        this.subject.next(data);
    }
    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }

}
```

Data are not available in sign-up component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {SharedService} from "../../services/shared.service";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-page-sign-up',
    styles: [],
    templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html'
})

export class PageSignUpComponent {
    private subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private sharedService: SharedService
    ) {

    }


    ngOnInit() {

        this.subscription = this.sharedService.getData().subscribe(
            data => {

                console.log(data, "Data"); //not getting here
            });    
    }
```

Comment: Will you please post full code of each compoennt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Data are not available in sign-up component

It's because `Subject` does not cache anything. When you emit something to it, only subscribers that are *currently* subscribed will get the message. Otherwise the message is lost forever.

If you want the value to be cached, use a `BehaviorSubject` instead.

**See also:**

- [Angular 2 special Observables (Subject / Behaviour subject / ReplaySubject)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43118769/2587435)

Comment: Bull's eye, didn't have a clue aboud BehaviorSubject. Thanks!

Comment: One small question . Why it needs to be an Observable ? Why can't it be a simple service as in case of Angular 1 .

Comment: I've been struggling with this for way too long because I didnt know Subject did not cache. Thanks