# Behaviour subject initial value null?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

```
private customer: Subject<Object> = new BehaviorSubject<Object>(null);

setCustomer(id, accountClassCode) {
    this.customer.next({'id': id, 'accountClassCode': accountClassCode});
}

getCustomer() {
    return this.customer.asObservable();
}
```

I'm using this part of code but I'm getting an error that can not find id of null. Is there any solution to get initial value that is not null?

Comment: Did you try an empty object? new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});

Comment: im gettin an error Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: There's a solution. Do not use BehaviorSubject if you don't need initial value.

Comment: I dont need inital value but my service is not working if i dont use BehaviorSubject

Comment: Is it an option to use `new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});` instead?

Comment: I don't understand, why not just use new Subject<Object>()

Comment: @windmaomao because if you then have any new subscriptions created afterwards they ever won't get that value

Comment: @dotbert not really in this case :-) the aim here is not to trigger the subscription handler unless there's a value that needs processing.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

The purpose of `BehaviorSubject` is to provide initial value. It can be `null` or anything else. If no valid initial value can be provided (when user id isn't known yet), it shouldn't be used.

`ReplaySubject(1)` provides a similar behaviour (emits last value on subscription) but doesn't have initial value until it is set with `next`.

It likely should be

```
private customer: Subject<Object> = new ReplaySubject<Object>(1);
```

Comment: The default is 1 if you don't specify it, so `new ReplaySubject<Foo>()` is better. Specifying the type does nothing at runtime btw, but provides type safety at compile time.

Comment: If you're interested here's the source code : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/ReplaySubject.ts

Comment: Prefer `ReplaySubject.create<Object>(1)`

Comment: @RomanTikhonov You likely don't want to do that. It's not the same thing. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45912937/3731501 .

Comment: @Simon_Weaver the current default (Nov 2019) is infinity. setting 1 is required.
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject

Comment: Thank you a lot. How can I map pairwise result to object with keys: {one: value, two: value}?

Comment: @Mamkad Likely with basic destructuring, `map(([one, two]) => ({ one, two }))`

Comment: How to get the `Data` out?

Comment: @lolelo The same way as with any other observable, by using subscribe() or converting it to a promise.

Comment: Since `BehaviorSubject` where updating for every same value. I made a `Set` extension method that checks the current value.
Also I believe I need current value in other places

Comment: @lolelo Was the question about ReplaySubject or BehaviorSubject? I'm not totally sure what is your case, but BehaviorSubject has `value` property, exactly because it always has a value. Other subjects and observables don't. In case you want to be able to always get current value from other kinds of subjects, you need to extend them and expose it in the same way that BehaviorSubject 
 does, https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts#L37

Comment: I would like to have access to current value but I don't want the initial subscribe trigger. 

Thanks. I just realized this was marked as rxjs I am .Net. Unfortunately the C# implementation loos more complicated: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Subjects/BehaviorSubject.cs

Comment: @lolelo I see. I don't deal with net, but probably the option would be the same, to extend replay subject class and override next method to expose current value on an instance.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you for your great post. You helped me allot. Attaching example from my code for others to user (tested working)  private _user$=  new ReplaySubject<User>();     this._user$.next(user) ;

Comment: ReplySubject will not hold value in it, every time we need to subscribe and get it. we can assign empty value as an initial value in behaviour subject

private customer = new BehaviorSubject<Customer>({} as Customer);

Answer (score 19):

Since the object can be null, a better choice is to infer the type like this

```
 private customer = new BehaviorSubject<Customer|null>(null);
```

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: private customer = new BehaviorSubject<Customer>({} as Customer); 
could be better which will avoid defining null to the assigning variables.

Answer (score 5):

Try structuring this way your service:

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    customerUpdate$: Observable<any>;

    private customerUpdateSubject = new Subject<any>();

    constructor() {
        this.customerUpdate$ = this.customerUpdateSubject.asObservable();
    }

    updatedCustomer(dataAsParams) {
        this.customerUpdateSubject.next(dataAsParams);
    }
}
```

Remember to add `MyService` to providers.

Where you update your client (if this is the case), you do something like this:

**Component (The one that triggers):**

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        // I'll put this here, it could go anywhere in the component actually
        // We make things happen, Client has been updated
        // We store client's data in an object
        this.updatedClient = this.myObjectWithUpdatedClientData;  // Obj or whatever you want to pass as a parameter
        this.myService.updatedCustomer(this.updatedClient);
    }
```

**Component (The one that is Subscribed):**

```
this.myService.customerUpdate$.subscribe((updatedClientData) => {
            // Wow! I received the updated client's data
            // Do stuff with this data!
        }
    );
```

From what I understood, you are trying to pass data from 1 component to another. You get your Client's data and send it over your App to another component, right? That's why I posted this solution.

If you are interested in other types of subscriptions, read this:

[Angular 2 special Observables (Subject / Behaviour subject / ReplaySubject)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118769/angular-2-special-observables-subject-behaviour-subject-replaysubject)

Comment: Hm, I copy-pasted the exact solution and it doesn't work for me for some reason, very strange.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use pipe to filter until a non-null value is received. It can be done with takeWhile also.

`.pipe(filter(val => !!val)).subscribe(x => {});`

Comment: ... or `pipe(skipWhile(val => !!val))`

Answer (score 2):

I have found many cases where I want the simplicity of `ReplaySubject(1)` but also want the `value` property of `BehaviorSubject`, i.e. it stores your most recent value for retrieval without having to subscribe. And using `BehaviorSubject` was always annoying given the need for an initial value that gets broadcast, a condition I rarely wanted. To that end I created my own `CurrentSubject`.

```
import { ReplaySubject } from "rxjs";

export class CurrentSubject<T> extends ReplaySubject<T> {
    value: T;

    set(value?: T) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next(value);
    }
}
```

I wanted to override the `next` method but I couldn't get that to work for some reason, so I settled on a method called `set`. My override attempt looked like this...

```
export class CurrentSubject<T> extends ReplaySubject<T> {
    value: T;

    next(value?: T) {
        this.value = value;
        super.next(value);
    }
}
```

I don't know why overriding didn't work.

Comment: what was the problem? do you need to call super() inside the constructor here?

Comment: The problem with attempting to override next? I dunno, I never solved that and instead opted for the set property as I outlined. If you want to try explicitly adding a constructor and calling super() just to see if that somehow works let me know! :)

Comment: I also had the same problem when I attempted to override next. Through debugging, I noticed that without overriding, when ```next``` is called on the extension class, ```nextInfiniteTimeWindow``` is actually executed by ```ReplaySubject```, but when overriding ```next``` and calling ```super.next```, it's ```next``` from the ```Subject``` class that get called instead of ```nextInfiniteTimeWindow```. I didn't bother fixing the problem so I instead wrapped the ```ReplaySubject``` class in my own class and exposed the same methods.

Comment: The same is happening for me as well that I can't override the `next` method with the latest versions of TypeScript & RxJS. Any idea?

Comment: Explained the problem here- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69696916/2405040