# Difference between new Observable(...) and Rx.Observable.create(...)?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm updating our software substituting all promises (and other hairy junk) for observables. To make sure that I'm following best practices, I made a quick googlearch and noticed that in [some cases](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/error_handling.html), the suggested syntax is by instance whereas in [other cases](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html), the examples perform a call by factory.

```
const byInstance = new Observable(_ => { ... });

const byFactory = Rx.Observable.create(_ => { ... });
```

I'm curious what's the actual difference. Are they precisely interchangeable? Is it an older/newer syntax/approach? Is it framework related? And, of course, which is to be preferred (**under the condition that** it's not opinionated, disputed etc.).

Comment: In the current version, there is no difference. The factory method [just calls the constructor](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.3/src/Observable.ts#L56-L58). As to which is preferred, the [doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#creating-observables) suggests the factory, but whether or not that's a definitive answer: who knows? Not me.

Comment: @cartant I've performed an **immensely** quick and **highly** unscientific inquiry to find any indications whether there's a trend on who/when/why uses the two alternatives. It seems that the more Angular or .NET background, the more likely to see `new Observable` syntax. I can't vouch for any of it but still...

Comment: I think the accepted answer makes a good point - it got my vote - re: chaining and usage elsewhere. Anyway, I use the factory method, but try to avoid creating custom observables in the first place.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no difference. `Observable.create` [calls `new Observable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.3/src/Observable.ts#L49-L58).

As [the manual](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#anatomy-of-an-observable) says,

> Observables are created using Rx.Observable.create or a creation
>   operator
>
> <...>
>
> Rx.Observable.create is an alias for the Observable constructor

`Observable.create` is conventionally used, probably because it reads better in chains and conforms with other `Observable` static methods that create observables, too.

The difference may appear in child classes. For example, `Subject.create` is equal to `AnonymousSubject.create` and not equal to `new Subject`. Usually `Subject.create` is the one that provides desirable behavour, while `new Subject` is more low-level. This confirms the point about the convention.

On the other hand, some classes (notably `BehaviorSubject`) are supposed to be used with `new` because `create` signature doesn't allow to provide the desired behaviour to them.

Comment: hey estus! do you have any sources/links about what you explained here? I would like to take a further look!

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Primarily my own experience with observables and third-party code that uses them. Added a reference to the manual. I would suggest to check source code first, it's the best way to figure out how Observable and Subject work internally. The parts that affect observable creation are rather simple.

Answer (score 6):

[The two are interchangeable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/4fa9d016a83049d014d77b89c56301e42db16b4d/src/internal/Observable.ts#L56), but the inline documentations says that [`Observable.create` is deprecated](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L54) ([future proof link here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/4fa9d016a83049d014d77b89c56301e42db16b4d/src/internal/Observable.ts#L54)).