# Angular 5.2.0: Cannot read property of undefined in ngZone.run

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, ngzone

I'm completely new to Angular, so I hope I can describe my problem clearly. I'm trying to get the date property from an observable to display it in KendoUI datetime picker in frontend.

Here is my source code:
I have an object `ResultObject` with 2 properties `(id, myCustomDate)`. The `id` property is of type `number` and the `myCustomDate` property is of type `Date`.

I got my data over a REST API request. Here is the call:

```
this.httpService.get<ResultObject>(this.service.Url + "getresultobject", { blockUi: true }).
    subscribe(result => this.result$.next(result));

//this is where I get the result through a web service call:
result$: Subject<ResultObject> = new BehaviorSubject<ResultObject>(null);

//this is where I create my observable, in the constructor:
this.resultObeservable$ = this.result$.map(r => r);
```

And here is the main problem which I have, I'm trying to assign a the property date from the object result:

```
this.resultObeservable$.subscribe(d => this.ngZone.run(() => {
   console.log(d);
   this.myCustomDate= d.resultDate; //----> here i get the exception
}));
```

The exception says that `d` is `null` or `undefined`.

As I said, I'm totally new to Angular and I even don't know if the usage of `ngZone` is correct like this. So it would be great if I get any help.

Comment: I don't see any code which executes a HTTP request. Could you share that code with us? Are you sure you're still using Angular 2? 6 is the latest version.

Comment: If the initial value of the BehaviorSubject `result$` is `null`, you may prefer to use another kind of Subject. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44693438/1009922).

Comment: @DavidWalschots, im using 5.2.0. I will correct it. The http code is only for the website call. I will add it anyway

Comment: I'm not sure why you have these additional observables and subjects. Is there a reason you don't simply in `httpService.get.subscribe` write `this.myCustomDate = result.resultDate`?

Comment: Change `this.resultObeservable$ = this.result$.map(r => r);` to `this.resultObeservable$ = this.result$.asObservable()`. Does that work?