# Override the Subject.next method

Tags: typescript, rxjs, subject

I have the following code, in which I wanna override the `next` to have some custom logic. It doesn't work this way, but only works if the `next` is a property with an arrow function. What's the reason behind it?

```
export class Store<T> extends ReplaySubject<T | undefined> {
  next(value?: T) {
    console.log("do something in my code");
    super.next(value);
  }
}
```

```
export class Store<T> extends ReplaySubject<T | undefined> {
  next = (value?: T) => {
    console.log("do something in my code");
    super.next(value);
  };
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-override-subject-next

Comment: Subjects can be `Observer` so it's kind of expected, but when it comes to `ReplaySubject` it doesn't seem to implement `SubjectLike`. So bit confused here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subject (and Observables) takes an Observer object with methods like `next`:

```
const observer = {
  next: () => {},
  error: () => {},
  complete: () => {},
};
```

You can provide this object to the Subject (preferably Observable) instead of extending it:

```
const subject = new Subject();

const observer = {
  next: (val) => { ... custom logic };
  < ... > 
}

subject.asObservable().subscribe(observer);
```

Comment: If it doesnt fit your needs, please share why

Comment: You got a point here, but I'm extending ReplaySubject, and it has the method next which I should be able to override. My question is why can't I do it... Going through the RxJs code I see it should be possible, can't see why it doesn't work.

Comment: ReplaySubject already extends Subject, so you would need mixins (I never used this techniques myself, though)

Answer (score 2):

Today, I also end up extending `ReplaySubject` to get the last value. For that, I raised a PR- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/6652/files but to workaround in my project meanwhile, I extended the `ReplaySubject` and the same happened with me; the `next` was not being overwritten.

I drove myself crazy that why this is happening. I jumped into the source code and saw that in the RxJS 6.x version, the `next` method id is being overwritten by function assignment- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.6.7/src/internal/ReplaySubject.ts#L31 and that's why it's not getting overwritten.

Following the history of the same file, I found that this behaviour got changed in v7.x ([7.0.0-beta.6](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#700-beta6-2020-09-23) to be specific) in this commit- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/commit/f1dcada1e1838ffb01cd0dac60340c6fa068f3cf#diff-a287f66fc20bf26caa2f42935756aa6a094f400e91d6b4a388aee4e4e11675c4.

So you have to upgrade to RxJS 7.x version to make it work.

If you can't upgrade to 7.x version- here is the workaround-

```js
export class Store<T> extends ReplaySubject<T | undefined> {

  private originalNext: any;

  constructor(bufferSize: number, windowTime: number) {
    super(bufferSize, windowTime);
    this.originalNext = super.next;
    this.next = this.emit;
  }

  private emit(value?: T): void {
    console.log("do something in my code");
    super.next(value);
  };
}
```

Cheers!