# Is there an equivalent to BehaviorSubject that doesn't require an initial value and is able to provide the current value?

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject, subject

Looking for the same functionality as `BehaviorSubject` but without having to provide an initial value.

I often need to subscribe to a subject before my data gets loaded from whatever source I load it from. I also need the subscription to fire immediately after subscribing if and only if `next()` was previously called on the subject and I expect it to show me the last emitted value, as well as be able to get the current value synchronously at any point in time, similar to the `value` field of `BehaviorSubject`.

Here's what I tried:

- `Subject`, but it doesn't emit the old value immediately after subscribing to it like `BehaviorSubject` and I can't retrieve the current value.
- `ReplaySubject` with a buffer of size 1, but this also doesn't allow retrieval of the current value.
- `BehaviorSubject.create()` instead of `new BehaviorSubject<Whatever>(null)` but this just doesn't do anything when calling `next()`. No value is emitted and the subscription code never fires.
- `BehaviorSubject` with `.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe` but if I run this code after I called `next()` then I loose that old but valid value, only firing after `next` is called again.

The only solution I came up with is to extend the `ReplaySubject` class to add a private field for the current value, which gets set when `next()` is called, and a getter to retrieve it.

I always expect these values to be defined and valid, so I don't understand why I have to provide a default null/undefined value to `BehaviourSubject` for an object type that I specifically expect to not be undefined/null and explicitly defined them accordingly, and then write an if statement in every subscription to check every time a new value is emitted if it is valid.

I also don't understand why must it emit that null value and cause each subscription to fire for no good reason each time I subscribe to the subject before I load the data.

So is there any alternative I have missed?

Edit: So far, the answer to my question seems to be that no, there isn't an equivalent. As such, I'm providing my work around for anyone who's looking for the same behavior:

```js
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

export class SensibleSubject<T>
{
    private replaySubject: ReplaySubject<T>;
    private _canGetValue = false;
    private _value!: T;

    public get value()
    {
        if (!this._canGetValue)
            throw new Error("Attempted to retrieve value before it has been set!");

        return this._value;
    }

    constructor()
    {
        this.replaySubject = new ReplaySubject<T>(1);
    }

    public next(value: T)
    {
        this._canGetValue = true;
        this._value = value;
        this.replaySubject.next(value);
    }

    public asObservable()
    {
        return this.replaySubject.asObservable();
    }

    public canGetValue()
    {
        return this._canGetValue;
    }
}
```

Initially, I specified that I extended the `ReplaySubject` class but, as crowmagnumb points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63160884/1969903) to [Behaviour subject initial value null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693438/behaviour-subject-initial-value-null), overriding `next` on the `ReplaySubject` somehow breaks it. I instead decided to wrap the `ReplaySubject` and expose the desired methods and fields.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```js
src = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
obs$ = src.asObservable.pipe(filter(value => !!value));
```

Since you say all the values emitted to the source will be valid and not `undefined`, the `filter` pipe will only filter the initial default `null`. This way you don't have to do an `if` check in each subscription and still get to keep the synchronous `getValue()` function.

Comment: Yeah, but if instead of type ```any``` I provide an actual type to the BS (what a lovely coincidence that the initials match that of another equally useful concept), I get ```Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type'[whatever type I specified]'.``` If I leave type ```any```, I loose type enforcing and all that jazz.

Comment: Union types? `new BehaviorSubject<someType | null>(null);`

Comment: I guess, but if I do that, then typescript wants me to explicitly cast the emitted value to ```someType```:
```someBsObservable.subscribe(result => this.someValue = result as someType)``` Otherwise I get nagged with ```Type 'someType | null' is not assignable to type 'someType'```

Comment: If you want a specific behavior from a multi-cast observable, you need to implement your own in that case. Both [`BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts) and [`ReplaySubject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/ReplaySubject.ts) are an extension of `Subject`. You could start from there. Using standard multi-cast observables however you need to cast it like you said.

Comment: The solution I mentioned does exactly what I need, without casting. I'm just curious if that's the way to go or if there's actually an alternative I've missed.

Comment: @user1969903: No you have not

Comment: Could you please clarify the last comment? It's not clear if no, I have no other alternative or no, that is not the way to go or no, I have not mentioned a valid solution.

Comment: I meant you have not missed any other options you've mentioned to the question "_Is there an equivalent to BehaviorSubject that doesn't require an initial value and is able to provide the current value?_"

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've edited in my remaining proverbial 2 cents. I guess you can change your answer to add "No, there is no equivalent..." before your suggestion and I'll accept it. If the Angular / RxJS teams decide to implement this, we can update the answer.