# Angular 2: Data Persistent

Tags: angular, data-persistence, angular-state-managmement

I am new to `Angular` and have a query regarding data persistent. I have a scenario where I have to persist data. I am on my `homepage` component where I have a personal details form which is reactive on `/personaldetails` `path`. User needs to fill data and `click` on the next button to move to the next page on the path `/education` where there is another `form`.

It may happen user feels he has to correct some data on personal details page. He clicks on back `button` and moves from `/education` to `/personaldetails`.

Here I want to persist data. I want that data in the input field to be as it is which was enter by user when he was on `/personaldetails`.

**How can I achieve this?**

Please share any working code or any reference which will help me.
I tried searching similar queries but no luck.

Comment: You can save the data server side between each step, or use `localStorage` on the client

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387889/passing-data-with-subjects-and-proxies/49388249#49388249

Comment: @David: I wouldn't recommend this, because localStorage survives the session. So there is a slight change that "old" data gets prompted when the user opens the app days later.

Answer (score 0):

Use a service to persist the entries:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class StorageService {

        private value: string;

        constructor() { }

        getValue(): string {
           return this.value;
        }

        setValue(value: string) {
            this.value = value;
        }
   }
```

When the user clicks "next" you simply store his entries inside this service.
When the user clicks "back" you can get the already entered values from the service.

Attention! You have to import and provide this service by the corresponding module.

And in your component you do it this way:

```
import {StorageService} from 'storage.service.ts';

constructor(
 private storageService: StorageService
){}

private saveEntries(): void {
  this.storageService.setValue(entries);
}
```

Of course "entries" doesn't have to be a string. It can be any kind of primitive or object.

Comment: It depends what OP wants. If he wants data to persist if the use refreshes the page, this won't work

Comment: Point taken. But even then I'd suggest to use the sessionStorage instead of the localStorage, because if one closes the browser, the sessionStorage get's killed, the localStorage not.