# Recall component on change variable Angular > 4

Tags: angular, angular5

I call the  component( selector = ngx-ebar-treemo) in  main component like this

```
<ngx-ebar-treemo *ngIf="type=='Bar' && graphic" type1="{{type1}}" type2="{{type2}}"></ngx-ebar-treemo>
```

i must recall him when variables type1 or type2 changes.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by recall him you want to re-instantiate the component or you just want to pass the values from parent to child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Pass data from parent to child with `input binding` or use a service for communication

in your child-component declare two input properties, with `@Input` decorators.
and `OnChanges()` can be used for change detection of input properties

> Angular provides lifecycle hooks for change detection. `OnChanges` is
>   an interface and has a method declaration i.e `ngOnChanges()` . In
>   parent-child component, the child component declares `@Input()`
>   property to get values from parent component. Whenever parent
>   component changes the value of properties used in child component
>   decorated with `@Input()` then the method `ngOnChanges()` created in
>   child component runs automatically

```
import {Component, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, Input} from '@angular/core';
        export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
        @Input() type1:any;
        @input()type2:any;

       ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
              for (let propName in changes) {  
                let change = changes[propName];
                 let curVal  = JSON.stringify(change.currentValue);
                 let prevVal = JSON.stringify(change.previousValue);
                  console.log(curVal);
                 console.log(prevVal);//your logic
 }
    ......
            }
```

In your main component

```
    export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
               type1:any;
               type2:any;
           yourCustomEvent()
             {//your logic to change the value
             this.type1=somevalue;
             this.type2=somevalue2;
}
                }
```

main.html

```
<ngx-ebar-treemo *ngIf="type=='Bar' && graphic" [type1]="type1" type2="type2"></ngx-ebar-treemo>
```

you can also use service for the communication See my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49388249/5695162)

Answer (score 0):

Use @Input in the component.
Inside the Component(ngx-ebar-treemo) use the ngOnChanges method.

```
ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChanges){
// your code here
}
```

This method will be called every time there is a change in type value.

Comment: How can i send to child with Output. Sorry i am beginner in angular

Comment: Just one example

Comment: @Arvind Muthuraman `@Output` is used to communicate from child to parent, not the other way round

Comment: Sorry. I misinterpreted the question. Thought the other way. I have updated the answer. Should use `ngOnChanges` method.