# `ngOnChanges` need clarification to understad

Tags: angular

In angular there is a method called `ngOnChanges`. i am trying to understand that,I tried with this code. but i am not getting any output.

any one help me to understand?

here is my code :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { StorageService } from '../shared/service/storage.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

    link = {};

    constructor(private storage:StorageService) {
        setTimeout(()=> {
            this.link = "ariffff";
        }, 1000 );
        // console.log( this.storage.name);
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
      console.log(this.link, changes); //getting nothing
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't have any inputs to that component, what were you expecting to trigger the method? I'd recommend reading the descriptions in https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks.

Comment: Agreed with @jonrsharpe, you can't say something doesn't work when you don't know how it works. Similarly, you can't try to understand something based solely on its name. Read the documentation, it's there for a reason.

Comment: I have a object in service file. which is updated by some of component. when the object change how can observe? so i will take some decision to other component

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49388249/5695162)

Answer (score 2):

**How To Use:**

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
 @Input()
 prop: number;

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
// changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
 }
}
```

**Description**

> `ngOnChanges` is called right after the data-bound properties have
>   been checked and before view and content children are checked if at
>   least one of them has changed. The `changes` parameter contains the
>   changed properties.

From https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Answer (score 0):

Per https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges:

> Lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes.

For further clarification: Components are a subset of Directives (https://angular.io/api/core/Component). So for example if you have a child component whose input prop changes the function is called. Since your Component doesn't have a data-bound property which is changing, your `ngOnChanges()` won't be called.

By the way, it is good practice to implement the `OnChanges` interface:

```
class MyComponent implements OnChanges
```