# Persist class property Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have an SearchComponent (route: /search) and SearchDetailComponent (route: /search-detail:id).

The SearchComponent contains an searchbox (input field) where I can type any text to start a search.

Now after loading the search results an navigating to the SearchDetail page, I want to save the search term I typed into the searchbox.
But **only** after routing back from the Detail page. So if I navigate back from detai page, the same text I searched for should be in the searchbox.

The searchbox should be empty while navigating to the search site by any other page.

Has anyone an example or suggestion how to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use a `Service` or `localStorage/Session Storage` for Persisting Data.

`localStorage` and `sessionStorage` accomplish the exact same thing and have the same API, but with `sessionStorage` the data is persisted only until the window or tab is closed, while with `localStorage` the data is persisted until the user manually clears the browser cache or until your web app clears the data.

I would suggest you to go for [**@ngx-pwa/local-storage**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage) Async local storage for Angular

## For Angular 5:

```
npm install @ngx-pwa/local-storage@5
```

**Register it in your RootModule**

```
import { LocalStorageModule } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LocalStorageModule,
    ...
  ]
```

**Inject and use it**

```
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

@Injectable()
export class YourService {

  constructor(protected localStorage: LocalStorage) {}

}
```

**Usage**

```
let user: User = { firstName: 'Henri', lastName: 'Bergson' };

this.localStorage.setItem('user', user).subscribe(() => {});
```

After you navigate back and forth just set/patch the values using one of these methods `setValue()` and `patchValue()` both sets the value in `form control` of `FormGroup`.

**Service**
Create a Service and Register the  it in an Angular module rather than a component.

If you want an instance of a dependency to be shared globally and share `state` across the application  configure it on the `NgModule.`

You could either use `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` to accomplish it.

1. **[Using Subject](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)**
2. **[Using BehaviorSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49388249/5695162)**