# How to pass an element to another component (easiest way)?

Tags: angular

I have a `string` in one of the components and I would like to send it to another component when the `submit` button is pushed. I found solutions (input, emit...) but none of them worked.

This is my component from where I'd like to pass the variable:

```
export class UsersComponent {
  public data: string;

  public exportDocument() { // This function is called, when the submit button is pushed!
     this.data = doc.output("datauristring");
     // I have no idea what to write here, to pass this variable
  }
}
```

Other component:

```
export class CvPageComponent implements OnInit {
  public cvData; // This should be equal with the value of "data"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Data with Subjects and Proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387889/passing-data-with-subjects-and-proxies)

Comment: How is `UsersComponent` related to `CvPageComponent`? Are they siblings? Is one the parent of the other? Also why didn't input and emit work? Please share what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have parent child relationship then you can use **@Input** way parent to child [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular)

**ViewChild or Sharing Data via Output() and EventEmitter** for child to parent

If they are not related components. You can use

**Sharing Data with a Service** as a way [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/communicating-through-components-with-services)

**storage method** as a way you can use sessionStorage or localStorage etc...

**sending parameter within url** as a way [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

In your cvPageComponent.html you use output

`<user-component (cvData) = "getCvData($event)">`

on your page you create a method that handle your cvDate like this:

```
public getCvData(cvData: any) { 
    // your code

  }
```

and in your userComponent you should mark cvData as output value like this

`@output() cvData: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>`

in your method:

```
public exportDocument() { 
// This function is called, when the submit button is pushed!
     this.data = doc.output("datauristring");
     cvData.emit(this.data);
  }
}
```