# Angular 7 - Use BehaviorSubject for Publishing API Results to All Components

Tags: angular, global-variables, behaviorsubject

I have an API call that returns data about the current user (i.e., username, full name, authorization group memberships, email address, etc.). I would like to only call this API once per user session and have its data shared among all components.

I don't want to rely upon localStorage, since I don't want this data to be modifiable by the user. I am trying to use a BehaviorSubject and have tried following a number of examples, but I keep receiving the initial value (null) when trying to access it via my components.

```
// HTTP Service:
getUserData() {
  const url = `${baseUrl}/api/users/`;
  return this.httpClient.get<UserData>(url).toPromise();
}
```

```
// Utils Service
export class UtilsService {
  private userDataSubject: BehaviorSubject<UserData>;

  constructor(
    private httpService: HttpService,
  ) {
    this.userDataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<UserData>(null);
    this.setUserData();
  }

  async setUserData() {
    let userData: UserData = await this.httpService.getUserData();
    this.userDataSubject.next(userData);
    console.log(this.userDataSubject.value); // Properly returns the data I want     
  }

  public get userDataValue(): UserData {
    return this.userDataSubject.value;
  }
```

```
// Component
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userData = this.utils.userDataValue; // This is the variable I need to set in my component.
    console.log(this.userData);               // Returns null
    console.log(this.utils.userDataValue);    // Also returns null
  }
```

I have also tried using an async function for userDataValue():

```
async userDataValue(): Promise<UserData> {
    return this.userDataSubject.value;
  }
```

And modified my component:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.userData = await this.utils.userDataValue();
    console.log(this.userData);                    // Still returns null
    console.log(await this.utils.userDataValue()); // Still returns null
  }
```

So far, I can only make this work if I avoid using a BehaviorSubject and call the API in each component, but that seems like it shouldn't be necessary. I'd greatly appreciate any guidance in how I can make this work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that `setUserData()` is an async function and it takes some time to `this.httpService.getUserData()` to fetch your data from backend. So when your component calls it `ngOnInit()` method `userDataSubject` hasn't yet  received the new value and that's why it returns null. I would suggest using BehaviorSubject `subscribe` handler so your code will do what it is supposed to do at the right time. It would be something like:

```
export class UtilsService {
  public userDataSubject: BehaviorSubject<UserData>;

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
    this.userDataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<UserData>(null);
    this.setUserData();
  }

  async setUserData() {
    let userData: UserData = await this.httpService.getUserData();
    this.userDataSubject.next(userData);     
  }
```

and in your component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.utils.userDataSubject.subscribe((data) => {
    if(data === null)
      return;

    console.log(data);

     // component logic to use your data
     // this will be called every time userDataSubject receives a new value
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried a solution similar to this, but was missing the "if (data === null) return" line, and was getting errors when trying to access any keys from userData.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little improvement of [alexortizl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58619288/6537157):

Instead of using the `BehaviorSubject<>` you should use the `ReplaySubject<>` of size 1. Why?
A `BehaviorSubject` must be initialized with a value. In your code, it is a `null`. That means: All subscribers must handle the `null` (like in alexortizl's answer, the `if(date === null)`-line).

On the other hand, a `ReplaySubject` of the size one will act like the `BehaviorSubject`, but doesn't have initial value. All subscribers will not get any value until the first correct value was emitted. Read this for a deeper dive -> [Subject vs BehaviorSubject vs ReplaySubject in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118769/subject-vs-behaviorsubject-vs-replaysubject-in-angular)

So, you code will look like this:

#### Service

```js
export class UtilsService {
  // we set the type to "Subject" to hide the actual ReplaySubject 
  public userDataSubject$: Subject<UserData> = new ReplaySubject(1);

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
    this.setUserData();
  }

  async setUserData() {
    let userData: UserData = await this.httpService.getUserData();
    this.userDataSubject$.next(userData);     
  }
```

#### Component.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.utils.userDataSubject$.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
     // component logic to use your data
     // this will be called every time userDataSubject receives a new value
  });
}
```

#### Component.html

... or even better with the `async`-pipe. Then you don't have to unsubscribe and it can improve the Change Detection of Angular. Deep dive -> [“SEEING” ANGULAR CHANGE DETECTION IN ACTION](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2018/07/02/seeing-angular-change-detection-in-action-part-ii-onpush-observables-and-the-async-pipe/)

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="utils.userDataSubject$ | async as userData">
    <span>Hello {{ userData.firstName }} {{ userData.lastName }}</span>
</ng-container>
```