# angular mat-table is not refreshing after insert

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, angular-material

I want to refresh my angular-material table (mat-table) when i insert a new book.
The table is not refrsh automatically, i must refresh the browser for seeing the new book inserted.

Steps to do it

1. Click to the "Create" button"
2. Fill all fields in the MatDialog
3. Click to the "ENVOYER" BUTTON
4. A new book is inserted in the database

But the table doesn't load the last book inserted automatically.

How can i tell to my booklistcomponent (angular component which shows the mat-table) to add automatically the new book without refresh the page.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogConfig, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Book } from '../models/book';
import { BookService } from '../services/book.service';
import { BookComponent } from '../book/book.component';
//import { BookComponent } from '../book/book.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-booklist',
  templateUrl: './booklist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./booklist.component.css']
})
export class BooklistComponent implements OnInit {

  public pbookList;

  booksResult: Book[] ;

  dataSource;

  searchKey: string;

 // private dialog: MatDialog;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['titre', 'auteur','isbn', 'date enregistrement', 'date publication', 'actions'];
  // dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Book>(this.booksResult);
  listData: MatTableDataSource<Book>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private bookService: BookService, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chargerLivres();
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Book>(this.booksResult);
  }

  applyFilter() {
    this.listData.filter = this.searchKey.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  chargerLivres(){
    console.log("list des books avant affcihage");
      this.bookService.loadBooks().subscribe(
              (result: Book[]) => {
                console.log("list des books : ",result);
                this.booksResult = result;
                this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(result);
                this.pbookList=result;
                console.log("bookResult : ",this.booksResult);
              },
              error => {
                console.log("Erreur : ",error);
              }
      );
  }

  onCreate() {
    this.bookService.initializeFormGroup();
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "60%";
    //dialogConfig.width = "350px";
    this.dialog.open(BookComponent,dialogConfig);
  }

}

<div class="container">
    <div fxFlex="60">
        <div class="search-div mr-2">
            <button mat-raised-button (click)="onCreate()">
              <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>Create
            </button>
            <mat-form-field class="ml-2 search-form-field" floatLabel="never">
              <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="applyFilter()">
              <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"*ngIf="searchKey"  (click)="onSearchClear()">
                <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
              </button>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="listData">

                
                <ng-container matColumnDef="titre">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Titre </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="auteur">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Auteur </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.author}} </td>
                </ng-container>

               
                <ng-container matColumnDef="isbn">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Isbn </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.isbn}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="date enregistrement">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date enregistrement </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.registerDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                
                <ng-container matColumnDef="date publication">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date publication </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.releaseDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                      <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>launch</mat-icon></button>
                      <button mat-icon-button color="warn"><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon></button>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>

            <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"></mat-paginator>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { Book } from '../models/book';
import { BookService } from '../services/book.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book',
  templateUrl: './book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book.component.css']
})
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {

  public book = new Book();

  constructor(public service: BookService, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<BookComponent>,@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.service.form.valid) {
      const formValue = this.service.form.value;
      this.book.author = formValue['auteur'];
      this.book.isbn = formValue['isbNum'];
      this.book.category = formValue['categ'];
      this.book.title = formValue['titre'];
      this.book.totalExamplaries = formValue['totExemplaire'];
      var localDate = new Date(formValue['publiDate']);
      if(localDate.getTimezoneOffset() < 0){
          localDate.setMinutes(localDate.getMinutes() - localDate.getTimezoneOffset() );
      }else{
        localDate.setMinutes(localDate.getMinutes() + localDate.getTimezoneOffset() );
      }
      this.book.releaseDate = localDate;
      if (!this.service.form.get('$key').value){
        //Insert the new book
        this.saveNewBook(this.book);
      }
      else {
        this.service.form.reset();
      }
    }
  }

  /**
* Save new book
* @param book
*/
saveNewBook(book: Book){
  this.spinner.show();
  this.service.saveBook(book).subscribe(
          (result: Book) => {
              console.log("Resultat du livre : ",result);
             if(result.id){
                this.spinner.hide();
                 console.log("Le livre a ajoute avec id : ",result.id);
             }
          },
          error => {
               this.spinner.hide();
               console.log("erreur survenue lors de  ajout : ",error);
          }
  );
}

  onClear() {
    this.service.form.reset();
    this.service.initializeFormGroup();
  }

  onClose() {
    this.service.form.reset();
    this.service.initializeFormGroup();
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  /**
* Save zone local date to the book releaseDate property : 
*   there is a recognized problem with datepicker @angular/material timezone conversion.
* @param book
*/
setLocalDateToDatePicker(book: Book){
  var localDate = new Date(book.releaseDate);
  if(localDate.getTimezoneOffset() < 0){
      localDate.setMinutes(localDate.getMinutes() - localDate.getTimezoneOffset() );
  }else{
    localDate.setMinutes(localDate.getMinutes() + localDate.getTimezoneOffset() );
  }
  book.releaseDate = localDate;
}

}

<mat-toolbar>
    <span>{{service.form.controls['$key'].value?"Modifier un livre":"Nouveau livre"}}</span>
    <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
    <button class="btn-dialog-close ml-auto" mat-stroked-button (click)="onClose()" tabIndex="-1"><mat-icon>clear</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <form [formGroup]="service.form" class="normal-form" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="300px">
      <mat-grid-tile>
        <div class="controles-container">
          <input type="hidden" formControlName="$key">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="titre" matInput placeholder="Titre*" >
            <mat-error>Le titre est obligatoire.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="auteur" matInput placeholder="Auteur*" >
            <mat-error>Le nom de l'auteur est obligatoire.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="isbNum" matInput placeholder="Isbn*" >
            <mat-error>L'isbn est obligatoire.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </mat-grid-tile>
      <mat-grid-tile>
        <div class="controles-container">
          <input type="hidden" value="test" name="test">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="totExemplaire" type="number" matInput placeholder="Total Exemplaires*" >
            <mat-error>Le nombre d'exemplaire est obligatoire.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="publiDate" [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker" matInput placeholder="Date publication*" >
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for] = "myDatepicker" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
            </mat-datepicker-toggle><mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
            <mat-error>Le date est obligatoire.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select formControlName="categ" placeholder="Categorie" >
              <ng-container >
                <mat-option value="C">Cuisine</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="I">Informatique</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="J">Jeunesse</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="M">Mathématiques</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="B">Bande dessiné</mat-option>
              </ng-container>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
          <div class="button-row">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="mr-2" type="submit" [disabled]="service.form.invalid">Envoyer</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onClear()">Effacer</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
  </form>
```

this is the stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/github/lnquaidorsay/bibliofront or https://jvmipwlay.github.stackblitz.io/books

Any idea ?

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: Hello,
Thank you very much, I solved my problem by applying your first method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is very similar to something that I have explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63888794/how-to-refresh-a-component-from-another-in-angular/63935918#63935918) in layman's terms. Please go through this first, so that you'll know what to do differently  here.

Although your `book.component` is responsible for adding new book and `booklist.component` is responsible for displaying all books, we need to refresh `booklist` from `book` but with a little TWIST.

I observed that you add new book via `book.component` and trigger `service.saveBook()`, and you trigger `service.loadBooks()` via `booklist.component` to load books data. You already have a service `book.service.ts` common to both. Good. The below steps are based on this assumption, kindly adjust them if assumps are misplaced.

WAY 1 - SIMPLER

Steps:

1. When you trigger `service.saveBook()` from `saveNewBook()` you need to call `Service.sendUpdate`(like the one in my answer) and simply send a flag (simple way) on success.

   ```
    saveNewBook(book: Book){
    this.service.saveBook(book).subscribe(
          (result: Book) => {
              console.log("Resultat du livre : ",result);
             if(result.id){
                 this.service.sendUpdate('A msg/flag');
                // rest code same
             }
          },
         //rest code same
         }
   ```
2. In the `book.service`, Once the `sendUpdate` is triggered, it will feed the value(lets say a flag) in the `Subscription` and automatically the Subscription calls for the `Observers`.
3. The Observer would be in our `booklist.component` and they will subscribe to it. It means that the booklist component would automatically know that a new book is added.
4. Toppings on the Icecream- Now while subscribing to it, you just need to trigger your `chargerLivres()` - which seems to be responsible for fetching.

   ```
    export class BooklistComponent implements OnDestroy {
    messageReceived: any;
    private subscriptionName: Subscription; //important to create a subscription

    constructor(pprivate bookService: BookService) {
        // subscribe to sender component messages
        this.subscriptionName= this.bookService.getUpdate().subscribe
         (message => { //message contains the data sent from service
         this.messageReceived = message; //kind of a flag here
         chargerLivres(); //or ngOnInit() whichever responsible for laoding
         });
   ```

Although the above Way was easy, questions can be raised on loading all books data on just one book addition!!. Hopefully we can tackle that too but with a bit extra work xD

WAY 2 -

1. When a book is successfully added via `saveNewBook()`, then trigger `sendUpdate` and send the result i.e. the details of the new book(and not a flag/msg)
2. Now when the result is fed into the subscription, then we can receive that book detail in our booklist component by subscribing to it.
3. In the booklist component, do NOT call the  `chargerLivres()`. Rather add that particular book detail into your existing data (the twist) and your data will refresh.

PS: I appreciate you uploading your file in stackblitz but your backend server is on your localhost xD. Consequently, it was difficult in understanding the api architecture.