# on First Click Rxjs not sending the value to other component in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to send ProductId from one component to another component using Rxjs in Angular 2+. So When I click the event function for first time Rxjs sendFucntion did not send the ProductId to other component. But on 2nd click it does.

Here is the code

```
Rxjs Class for handling send and get calls
      
 import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

 @Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
 })

export class MessengerService {
_Subject = new Subject;
 constructor() { }

   SendMessageWithData(MessageAndData){
      this._Subject.next(MessageAndData);
   }

  GetMessageWithData(){
      return this._Subject.asObservable();
   }
}

Component 1.ts
      SendProductId(_ProductId){
         //Here I am getting the Product id here successfully I cheecked it using console.log
        this._MessengerService.SendMessageWithData(_ProductId);
        this._Router.navigate(['viewProduct']);
    }


  Component2.ts
  ngOnInit(): void {

     //Setting the Local Storage
     this._MessengerService.GetMessageWithData().subscribe(docs=>{
         console.log(docs);
         this._EcommerceDataService.SetLocalStorageForProductId(docs);
     });
 }
```

Now this is my logic with code. But its not working for first click on fucntion but worked after first click . Please guide me Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the first notification is emitted before the subscription. RxJS `Subject` will only emit the notifications to observers that are already subscribed to. You could instead use `ReplaySubject` with buffer 1.

```js
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

export class MessengerService {
  _Subject = new ReplaySubject(1);

  constructor() { }

  SendMessageWithData(MessageAndData){
    this._Subject.next(MessageAndData);
  }

  GetMessageWithData() {
    return this._Subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Comment: Brother its working fine. But brother i need to understand this thing can you tell me any link or resource where i can learn this thing.
Or bro can you explain here in detail. thanks brother

Comment: And brother can I have your linkedin Please i wana connect with you .

Comment: @AbdulRehman: You could start here for resources: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43118769/6513921. LearnRxJS is also a good place to start. And while I'm pleased with request I don't unfortunately do LinkedIn at the moment. I'll update in the Stackoverflow Bio page if I ever get around to having one :)