# Deleting stored observable value in angular service

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular10

I have a observable service:

GetInputValueObservableService:

```
private inputObservable = new BehaviourSubject<string>(null);
setObservable(text) {
   this.inputObservable.next(text);
}
getObservable() {
   return this.inputObservable;
}
```

I have a component that sets/gets the input value on a click:

```
so if I have 'initial text' text showing up in html because inputObservable has null value initially and I click on a button that triggers observable and sets 'new text'
```

now I navigate to other page and come back it still shows 'new text' may be because inputObservable holds the new text, do I need to reset the value to null also?

I have unsubscribed the observable during **onDestory** of the component.

May be I am doing it incorrectly? Any Ideas?

Hints:
Subscription:

```
this.sub = this.getInputValueObservableService.subscribe((newText)=>{
   this.text = newText
})
```

onDestroy:

```
this.sub.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: can you please how you subscribe to that observable

Comment: hi @AlaaM.Jaddou added more code in the hints at the bottom

Comment: I think the value is still their coz of ```this.text``` variable not from the subscription. you can test that by clarifying the value or testing it by sending any other value from another page. if you get back the subscription will be created again :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the issue is using a `BehaviorSubject`. It can hold/buffer the current value and emit it immediately to future subscribers. Instead you could try to use RxJS `Subject`. It only starts emitting the notifications to observers that were pushed to it after the subscription.

You could find differences b/n different multi-cast observables [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43118769/6513921).

Try the following

**GetInputValueObservableService**

```js
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

private inputObservable: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();  // <-- no default value needed

setObservable(text) {
   this.inputObservable.next(text);
}

getObservable(): Observable<string> {
   return this.inputObservable.asObservable();
}
```

Nevertheless the unsubscription in the `ngOnDestroy()` must not be removed since without it duplicate subscriptions could occur.

Comment: that's correct, thank you for the solution and link also.

Answer (score 0):

Unsubscribing does not flush the value in observable. It's still there and when you navigate back to component and subscribe again, you'll get the latest value. If you want to do so, just before unsubscribe push a null to the observable.

```typescirpt
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  yourService.setObservable(null);
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}

// or create a function for that in your service
clearObservable(): void {
  this.inputObservable.next(null);
}
```

Comment: Yes as an alternative I have done that only. Isn't there any better way to flush the value rather broadcasting a null ?