# How to unit test MatSnackbar using Jasmine Karma in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I want to perform unit testing on this onSubmit function where the positive submission is leading to MatSnackbar with message, "Submitted Successfully". I am new to Jasmine Karma please guide me about the testing of MatSnackbar in this case.

***Component.ts***

```js
import { MatSnackBar } from "@angular/material/snack-bar";

  constructor(
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private auth: AuthenticateService,

  ) {}
...
...
  onSubmit(e) {
    const newYellow = {
      G1: e.value.Yellow_G1,
      G2: e.value.Yellow_G2,
      G3: e.value.Yellow_G3,
      G4: e.value.Yellow_G4,
      B1: e.value.Yellow_B1,
      B2: e.value.Yellow_B2,
      B3: e.value.Yellow_B3,
      B4: e.value.Yellow_B4,
    };
    console.log(newYellow);
    this.auth.submitnominYellow(newYellow).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.snackBar.open("Submitted Successfully", "", {
          duration: 2000,
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

This is code for `submitnomin` function.
***auth.service.ts***

```js
submitnominYellow(inpobj) {
    console.log(inpobj);
    return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/api/customize/yellow', inpobj);
}
```

My unit test case is somewhat like this.
***component.spec.ts***

```js
    const mockSnackbarMock = jasmine.createSpyObj(['open']);
    mockSnackbarMock.open
    
    const mockopblue =
      {
        success: true
    }
    
    const MockAuthService = {
      submitnominYellow:(id) => (mockopblue),
      getuser:() => (undefined)
    
    };
...
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ YellowCustomizeComponent ],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, MatSnackBarModule, FormsModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers:[{provide: MatSnackBar, useValue: mockSnackbarMock},
      {provide: AuthenticateService, useValue: MockAuthService}
      ]

    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
...

          fit('should open the snack bar with correct arguments when form submitted', () => {
            const e =  {
              value:{
                Yellow_G1: "YGirlName1",
                Yellow_G2: "GirlName2",
                Yellow_G3: "GirlName3",
                Yellow_G4: "GirlName4",
                Yellow_B1: "BoyName1",
                Yellow_B2: "BoyName2",
                Yellow_B3: "BoyName3",
                Yellow_B4: "BoyName4",
              }
              
            };
            component.onSubmit(e)
            console.log('mockSnackbarMock',mockSnackbarMock)
            // console.log('yellow onsubmit',component.onSubmit(e)); 
            expect(mockSnackbarMock.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Submitted Successfully", "", );
         })
```

Comment: If you want to just test the snack bar and not the entire method I would say to create a mock/stub authService with a stubbed submitnominYellow method that will return a success. You’ll want to use a fakeAsync test callback in the “it” test method. You can create a spy of the snackBar and its create method. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but snackbar is part of the function, so how will I proceed. Please guide me I am new to the jasmine karma unit testing.

Comment: Is `this.snackBar` a viewChild of component or what?

Comment: I am not understanding what you're trying to say. Please answer in the form of code.

Comment: ` Hitesh Agashe` may you please provide a piece of code where you declare `snackBar` property?

Comment: Edited sir, please check!

Comment: @IAfanasov Gentle reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the test, it is possible to change the dependency injection configuration so that instead of the `SnackBar` instance the mock would be provided. That is how to do it:

```js
const mockSnackbarMock = jasmine.createSpyObj(['open']);
mockSnackbarMock.open

await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                ...
            ],
            providers: [
                {provide: MatSnackBar, useValue: mockSnackbarMock},
            ],
            imports: [
                ...
            ],
        }).compileComponents();
```

Later on in the test after all the actions which trigger the snack bar, you can check if the open method was called correctly:

```js
it('should open the snack bar with correct arguments when form submitted', () => {
   //emulate submission

   expect(mockSnackbarMock.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Submitted Successfully", "", {duration: 2000});
})
```

Comment: can we chat in person? my code is too long to comment and I can't edit original question.

Comment: `Error: <toHaveBeenCalledWith> : Expected a spy, but got Object({ open: spy on unknown.open }).
Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...arguments)`

Comment: sorry, I missed a thing. Changed `expect(mockSnackbarMock)` to `expect(mockSnackbarMock.open)`

Comment: and sorry, chat in person would be too much of distraction

Comment: `Expected spy unknown.open to have been called with:
  [ 'Submitted Successfully', '' ]
but it was never called.`

Comment: You skipped the part: `after all the actions which trigger the snack bar`. I don't know how would you prefer to do it. You can consider emulating click on a button that triggers the snackbar or maybe just calling the method.

Comment: Onsubmit function triggers snackbar and I am already calling it

Comment: The expectation error message states that the `snackbar.open` method was not called.   Is there a chance that `this.auth.submitnominYellow(newYellow)` doesn't return a proper observable in the test?

Comment: Mock is returning the proper value, i checked. Should I add something in unit test case code??

Comment: it would be useful to show the unit test code (:

Comment: Unit test code added in question, please proceed.

Comment: I see the mock for the auth service is `const MockAuthService = {submitnominYellow:(id) => ({ success: true })};`. With such mock, during the test run the piece `this.auth.submitnominYellow(newYellow).subscribe` would be the equal to `true` and one should see an error ` true is not a function`. something doesn't match in that code. see how to setup a mock properly here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40240950/390161

Comment: Yup,   `submitnominYellow:(id) => of (mockopblue),`