# Unit testing of catcherror pipe function in angular service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I try to understand how to test this function. From `(err)=>{ line,` it's showing as an uncovered statement.
***service.ts***

```js
Deletevote(inp) {
   console.log(inp);
     
   return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/api/reset/abc', inp).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
         console.log('error caught in service');
         console.error(err);
         return throwError(err);
      })
   );
}
```

I have created this test case for positive flow, but err part is still not covered. Please guide me about how to create the error.

**service.spec.ts**

```js
const Mockcolor = 'green';
const MockGen = 'male';

it('submitnominGreen', () => {
    service.Deletevote(DeleteObj).subscribe((posts) =>{
      expect(posts).toEqual([Mockcolor,MockGen], 'should check mock data');
    });
    const req =  httpTestCtrl.expectOne(environment.apiUrl + '/api/reset/abc');
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('POST');
    expect(req.cancelled).toBeFalsy();
    req.flush([Mockcolor,MockGen])
});
```

Comment: Did you read https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-for-errors?

Comment: Yes but how should i code for my function?

Comment: They don't have pipe map in their code.

Comment: You can't expect the documentation to cover every possible kind of consuming code. That shows how to make an error happen in the test, then you have to apply that to your specific circumstances.

Comment: I am new contributor and I need code wise help. Unit testing doesnot have much reference material.

Comment: It has _loads_ of reference material, in the official docs alone there's what I've pointed you to as well as this whole section: https://angular.io/guide/testing.

Comment: Throwing errors for my code for httpClient

Comment: Again you _cannot_ expect the documentation, or anyone else's resource, to show your specific code. It's **your job** to apply the general information to your specific case. If you can't provide a [mre] of your attempt to do so, you might as well delete this question - this isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: `it('submitnominGreen', () => {
    service.Deletevote(DeleteObj).subscribe((posts) =>{
      expect(posts).toEqual([Mockcolor,MockGen], 'should check mock data');
    });
    const req =  httpTestCtrl.expectOne(environment.apiUrl + '/api/reset/abc');
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('POST');
    expect(req.cancelled).toBeFalsy();
    req.flush([Mockcolor,MockGen])
  });`

I tried this but still it's not covering error part. Please guide for errors part now

Comment: Please [edit] the question. But you don't actually seem to be creating an error state, so it's no surprise that part's not covered - maybe try _actually applying what the documentation suggests_.

Comment: Done everything, now please guide me codewise.

Comment: No you haven't. You have _one_ test, that appears to be for the happy path. Of course the other branch isn't covered.

Comment: Copy the code in your angular project or stackblitz and solve the problem, if you really want to!

Comment: Okay, For the last time I am asking what basic requirements do you want me to provide?
P.S. I am not getting how to create error so I can't give the error input test case.

Comment: Welcome to SO community, Sakthy Rupini! you did a great job refining the question. It would be beneficial for you and the community to finish the introductory tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour. It would help to increase your chances to get help. And would give you a badge (: Probably some points as well, which would give you more permissions here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code inside the `subscribe` of the unit test would not be executed. Karma would wait for all the sync execution to be finished and would consider the test finished before the async callback would be executed. As a solution, you might use the `done` callback to indicate when is the test finished manually.

You did a great job leveraging the HttpTestingModule for testing. It allows you to test the errors easily as well. Instead of `req.flush` you might use the `req.error` method to simulate the HTTP error.

```js
it('submitnominGreen', (done) => {
    const mockError = {error: 'someError'} as ErrorEvent;
    service.Deletevote(DeleteObj).subscribe(() => {}, (thrownError) =>{
      expect(thrownError.error).toEqual(mockError);
      done();
    });
    const req =  httpTestCtrl.expectOne(environment.apiUrl + '/api/reset/abc');
    req.error(mockError);
});
```

Take a look into the `Error handling` section of this nice article: [Testing Angular HTTP Communication](https://itnext.io/testing-angular-http-communication-9a120a10da18). It would be of help for some other scenarios as well.

Comment: I tried this code but in req.error line it's throwing this error `Argument of type 'Error' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ErrorEvent'.
  Type 'Error' is missing the following properties from type 'ErrorEvent': colno, error, filename, lineno, and 22 more.ts(2345)`

Comment: Now this is the error.

`Expected object to be a kind of Object, but was HttpErrorResponse({ headers: HttpHeaders({ normalizedNames: Map(  ), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(  ) }), status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/reset/abc', ok: false, name: 'HttpErrorResponse', message: 'Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/api/reset/abc: 0 ', error: Object({ error: 'someError' }) }).`

Comment: it starts to look like a google driven development (: @Sakthy Rupini, it is just a tiny step towards the solution. please read the error message.

Comment: I thought I had to remove as ErrorEvent, but it didn't work.

Comment: Hello Sakthy, I have added an edit to the answer, as soon as @IAfanasov will accept it, you'll get it correct. Till the time try to console thrownError as well as mockError object.

Comment: Hello @IAfanasov , My friend has a doubt in Unit testing. Please solve this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68334529/how-to-unit-test-matsnackbar-using-jasmine-karma-in-angular