# rxjs: Observable.of(...).delay is not a function

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, rxjs5

I would like to create a delayed observable in typescript by:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

...

const o = Observable.of(values).delay(10000);
o.subscribe((v) => { alert(v); });
```

but I got the following error:

```
"Observable_1.Observable.of(...).delay is not a function"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In rxjs6 operators can be found in the 'rxjs/operators/*' packages.

```js
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators/delay';

of(values).pipe(
    delay(1000)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

In older versions can import the **delay** operator separately.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
```

Comment: In rxjs6, the of function is imported like this import { Observable, Subject, of } from 'rxjs';. And used like this: of(values)

Comment: yeah  rxjs6 changed stuff. it would probably be easier to use pipeable operators from `'rxjs/operators/delay'`. I'll update the answer, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: This is a RxJS 5 question. Your solution for version 6 is not helpful.

Comment: In RxJS v6, `Observable.of()` becomes `of()`. See: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#umd-module-name-change <- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38067643/3102325

Comment: I find these docs to be the clearest: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/ - https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of

Answer (score 3):

In rxjs 6 this works fine:

```
import { Observable, of  } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

...    

const o = of(values).pipe(
  delay(10000)
);

o.subscribe( v => alert(v) );
```