# Type '{Property: string, Property2: string} is not assignable to type Observable<Filters[]>

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a method:

```
getFilters(): Observable<Filters[]> {
    let filters: Observable<Filters[]> = [
      {
        property: "Value",
        property2: "Value2"
     },
     {
       property: "Value3",
       property2: "Value4"
     }
  return filters;
}
```

I get an error:

> Type '{Property: string, Property2: string} is not assignable to type
>   Observable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an Observable:

```
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";

getFilters(): Observable<Filters[]> {
    let filters: Filters[] = [
      {
        property: "Value",
        property2: "Value2"
      },
      {
        property: "Value3",
        property2: "Value4"
      }
     ];
    return of(filters);
    }
```

Comment: I get an error of: Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

Comment: add the correct import `import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";`

Comment: @sander: `import { of } from 'rxjs';` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067580/property-of-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-observable?rq=1

Comment: @mrkernelpanic I posted an answer how I got it working, edit your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how observable works:

```
getFilters(): Observable<Filters> {
    let filters = [
      {
        property: "Value",
        property2: "Value2"
     },
     {
       property: "Value3",
       property2: "Value4"
     }
    ];
  return Observable.from(filters);
}
```

You can use it like:

```
// Prints out each item
let subscription = this.getFilters().subscribe(
x => console.log('onNext: %s', x),
e => console.log('onError: %s', e),
() => console.log('onCompleted'));

// => onNext: {property: "Value",property2: "Value2"}
// => onNext: {property: "Value3",property2: "Value4"}
```

Refer to [this](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html#converting-arrays-and-iterables-to-an-observable-sequence) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding to the imports:

```
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
```

Then doing

```
return of(filters);
```