# How to use the operator of with observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

So of course I googled a lot. For example this:

[Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067580/property-of-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-observable)

But what I try, it doesn't fix it.

So I have this:

```
import { Observable,} from "rxjs";
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';



export class TranslateServiceStub{

    public get(key: any): any {
        Observable.of(key);
    }
}
```

But it keeps saying this:

```
Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.ts(2339)
```

So what do I have to do to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: I google a lot...[Really?](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of)

Comment: As @Liam said in a comment, replace `Observable.of(key)` with `of(key)`.

Comment: Ohh, I didnt know that. yes, that is working :) thx

Comment: Also you likely want to return the observable, don't you? You forgot the return

Answer (score 1):

import of from 'rxjs' not 'rxjs/observable/of';

```
import { of} from "rxjs";
```

Comment: I tried that. I type: Observable, and even don't see the of command

Comment: could you explain more about your requirements ? from what you want to create an observable ?

Comment: This is correct but OP is also doing `Observable.of` when the correct syntax is just `of()`

Comment: For the spec. I want to inject the mock in the spec file

Comment: @savantCodeEngineer, in Rxjs 6 you use only `of(key)` and `import { of} from "rxjs";`. From Angular 6 it's used Rxjs 6, if you are using an old Angular 5 your code is correct

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing the function `of` from RxJS, why would you use it on observable ? just use it like that `of(key)`. You don't have to call any object before that.