# How do I resolve an Angular/rxjs/observable error?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

ref: Angular, Observable, rxjx 6.4.0

My code reads:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
...
return Observable.of(this.products);
...
```

The error reads:

```
Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
```

I can also remove the /add from the import since of.js exists on both folders.  But this returns the same error.

Comment: Have you read the guidance on upgrading to RxJS 6? E.g. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: The imports changed for RxJS v6. They are now: `from 'rxjs'` for an objects and creation functions and `from 'rxjs/operators'` for the operators. See this for more information: https://rxjs.dev/guide/v6/migration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067580/property-of-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-observable)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like:

```
 import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'

 return of(this.products);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, with that version of RxJs the static methods and operators are imported differently.

Here is an example from their [docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of):

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

of(10, 20, 30)
.subscribe(
  next => console.log('next:', next),
  err => console.log('error:', err),
  () => console.log('the end'),
);
// result:
// 'next: 10'
// 'next: 20'
// 'next: 30'
```

So your code would look like:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

...
return of(this.products);
...
```