# Best way to import Observable from rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

In my angular 2 app I have a service that uses the `Observable` class from the `rxjs` library.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

At the moment I am just using `Observable` so that I can use the `toPromise()` function.

I read in another StackOverflow question somewhere that importing in this way and also importing from `rxjs/Rx` will import a whole lot of unnecessary stuff from the `rxjs` library that will increase the page load times and/or the code base.

My question is, what is the best way to import `Observable` so I can use the `toPromise()` function without having to import everything else?

Comment: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';` would import the Observable, but you don't need to import it all if you are using promises... `toPromise` works without it.

Comment: What would I need to import by itself to use just `toPromise`? I am using Observable, I should have clarified that in the question. it's really two separate questions.

Comment: then this would do, if you want promises `import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';` Take a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html That should help you along :)

Comment: I'll look into it. Cheers and thanks for taking the time to share!

Comment: No problem! Happy coding! :)

Comment: This is no longer correct for rxjs 6+.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which part is incorrect, for other visitors to this page.

Comment: Please see my answer below for more info.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

### Rxjs v 6.*

It got simplified with newer version of rxjs .

#### 1) Operators

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

#### 2) Others

```
import {Observable,of, from } from 'rxjs';
```

Instead of chaining we need to pipe . For example

**Old syntax :**

```
source.map().switchMap().subscribe()
```

**New Syntax:**

```
source.pipe(map(), switchMap()).subscribe()
```

**Note:** Some operators have a name change due to name collisions with JavaScript reserved words! These include:

`do` -> `tap`,

`catch` -> `catchError`

`switch` -> `switchAll`

`finally` -> `finalize`

---

### Rxjs v 5.*

I am writing this answer partly to help myself as I keep checking docs everytime I need to import an operator . Let me know if something can be done better way.

### 1) `import { Rx } from 'rxjs/Rx'`;

This imports the entire library. Then you don't need to worry about loading each operator . But you need to append Rx. <s>I hope tree-shaking will optimize and pick only needed funcionts( need to verify )</s> As mentioned in comments , tree-shaking can not help. So this is not optimized way.

```
public cache = new Rx.BehaviorSubject('');
```

---

Or you can import **individual** operators .

**This will Optimize your app to use only those files** :

### 2) `import { _______ } from 'rxjs/_________';`

This syntax usually used for main Object like `Rx` itself or `Observable` etc.,

Keywords which can be imported with this syntax

```
 Observable, Observer, BehaviorSubject, Subject, ReplaySubject
```

### 3) `import 'rxjs/add/observable/__________';`

**Update for Angular 5**

With Angular 5, which uses rxjs 5.5.2+

```
import { empty } from 'rxjs/observable/empty';
import { concat} from 'rxjs/observable/concat';
```

These are usually accompanied with Observable directly. For example

```
Observable.from()
Observable.of()
```

Other such keywords which can be imported using this syntax:

```
concat, defer, empty, forkJoin, from, fromPromise, if, interval, merge, of, 
range, throw, timer, using, zip
```

### 4) `import 'rxjs/add/operator/_________';`

**Update for Angular 5**

With Angular 5, which uses rxjs 5.5.2+

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators/filter';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
```

These usually come in the stream after the Observable is created. Like `flatMap` in this code snippet:

```
Observable.of([1,2,3,4])
          .flatMap(arr => Observable.from(arr));
```

Other such keywords using this syntax:

```
audit, buffer, catch, combineAll, combineLatest, concat, count, debounce, delay, 
distinct, do, every, expand, filter, finally, find , first, groupBy,
ignoreElements, isEmpty, last, let, map, max, merge, mergeMap, min, pluck, 
publish, race, reduce, repeat, scan, skip, startWith, switch, switchMap, take, 
takeUntil, throttle, timeout, toArray, toPromise, withLatestFrom, zip
```

**FlatMap**: 
`flatMap` is alias to `mergeMap` so we need to import `mergeMap` to use `flatMap`.

---

**Note for `/add` imports** :

We only need to import once in whole project. So its advised to do it at a single place. If they are included in multiple files, and one of them is deleted, the build will fail for wrong reasons.

Comment: Tree-shaking can't optimize here as it relies on the symbol names of export and import definitions and RxJS operator modules don’t export anything, but change global state instead.
[see](https://christianliebel.com/2017/07/import-rxjs-correctly/)

Comment: I think you have to import any operator one by one like import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map }; import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators/filter }

Comment: groupBy didn't work for me on Angular 5+, others did though.

Comment: Great answer.  I didn't know the difference between `/add/operator` vs `/operators` imports.  Works like a charm.

Comment: This is no longer the case, rxjs 6 imports are now done directly on the 'rxjs' or 'rxjs/operators'  (or other submodules)

Comment: Cool, but where is that in the documentation? I find Rxjs documentation hard to use.

Answer (score 22):

**Update for RxJS 6 (April 2018)**

It is now perfectly fine to import directly from `rxjs`. (As can be seen in Angular 6+). Importing from `rxjs/operators` is also fine and it is actually no longer possible to import operators globally (one of major reasons for refactoring `rxjs 6` and the new approach using `pipe`). Thanks to this treeshaking can now be used as well.

Sample code from rxjs repo:

```
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

range(1, 200)
  .pipe(filter(x => x % 2 === 1), map(x => x + x))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

**Backwards compatibility for rxjs < 6?**

rxjs team released a [compatibility package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat) on npm that is pretty much install & play. With this all your `rxjs 5.x` code should run without any issues. This is especially useful now when most of the dependencies (i.e. modules for Angular) are not yet updated.

Comment: I had the problem in Angular 6.0.0-rc.5. And I didn't know that it was RxJS who had made the change. I also removed the filter from the pipe.

Comment: There are a lot of changes in RxJS6. Highly recommend taking the time to read this https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md and/or https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-rxjs-6/ so you can prepare for RxJs7 where things will really disappear. As @enn mentioned you now should be using `pipe` instead of chaining methods together

Comment: This article is great in explaining the benefits of `pipe` https://gofore.com/en/lettable-operators-and-rxjs-versioning/ (it is not specifically about version 6 but helped me understand why so many drastic changes in RxJS6 that aren't well explained in their own guide)

Answer (score 3):

One thing I've learnt the hard way is being consistent

Watch out for mixing:

```
 import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
```

with

```
 import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
```

This will probably work just fine UNTIL you try to pass the object to another class (where you did it the other way) and then this can fail

```
 (myBehaviorSubject instanceof Observable)
```

It fails because the prototype chain will be different and it will be false.

I can't pretend to understand exactly what is happening but sometimes I run into this and need to change to the longer format.

Comment: If someone can please explain this better please reply :-)

Comment: Visual Studio for instance will happily import from `"rxjs"` and merge definitions together where it seems you're better off doing them separately in the 'long' format.