# How to import only used operators in RxJS 6 like older RxJS without requiring rxjs-compat?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

Previously I was able to import only used operators with this code:

```
import 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

This generates a small bundle (vendor.ts).
How to do this with RxJS without requiring rxjs-compat?
Changing the code above to `import 'rxjs';` generates a bigger bundle.

UPDATE:

I followed all the answers you've posted but nothing works well.
This is my updated vendor.ts:

```
import 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/operators/map';
import 'rxjs/operators/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/operators/catchError';
import 'rxjs/operators/finalize';
```

I also tried using 'rxjs/add/operator/*'.

This is how I'm importing rxjs:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {_throw} from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import {mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators/mergeMap';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';
import {finalize} from 'rxjs/operators/finalize';
```

I changed my Webpack 3 configuration according to this document (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-and-treeshaking) and nothing works.

Finally, take a look at the Webpack Bundle Analyzer result:

[image]

The bundle includes all operators.
I found this related issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9069

Comment: rxjs-compat is intended exactly for this purpose.

Comment: @estus, but would not this library just be used to maintain compatibility with older versions? How to use this in the new way? Does not this exist without rxjs-compat?

Comment: That's the way it provides compatibility with older versions. By providing old import style.

Comment: @estus, but how to use only the new way, but reducing vendor size?

Comment: Same way as you would do with RxJS 5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376972/best-way-to-import-observable-from-rxjs . rxjs-compat needs to be installed, but you don't need to `require` it.

Answer (score 4):

`rxjs-compat` is supposed to be installed together with `rxjs`, it provides the support for old-style imports.

It's possible to use RxJS 6 the same way as RxJS 5:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

This compatibility layer is expected to be removed in RxJS 7.

Comment: Using this way will result in a smaller bundle?

Comment: This is same as in RxJS 5. Importing `Observable` from `rxjs/Observable` is how it's done (not from `rxjs/Rx`, never `import 'rxjs'` because omitted `from` results in importing the package entirely).

Comment: please check my update in the question. Nothing works fine.

Comment: I guess the problem is likely related to your build and not RxJS. Yes, the problem may be in Webpack. Usually RxJS 6 is used as a prerequisite with Angular 6. Why is Webpack 3 is in use? Did you try to switch to 4?

Comment: I had a lot of headaches to switch to Webpack 4 in the past, but I'm trying to update now.

Answer (score 2):

The issue for me was that I had `module` set to `commonjs` in tsconfig.json. It needs to be set to `es6`, because webpack needs es6 modules in order for it to be able to do tree shaking.

See more info in: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

> Tree shaking is a term commonly used in the JavaScript context for
>   dead-code elimination. It relies on the static structure of ES2015
>   module syntax, i.e. import and export...
>
> ...
>
> - Use ES2015 module syntax (i.e. import and export).
> - Ensure no    compilers transform your ES2015 module syntax into CommonJS modules

Answer (score 1):

Now You need to import functions that You want to use.

Never use

> import from 'rxjs'

Use with destructuring

> import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

Import operators from `'rxjs/operators'`

Static functions from `'rxjs'`

So, for example, you need to use operator 'map' you will import it

```
import { map } 'rxjs/operators';
```

And then you use it with pipe

```
observable.pipe(map(() => { some function }))
```

For better understanding read [Migration Guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) or watch awesome video from [ng-conf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCXZhe6KsxQ)

Comment: I'm using this way, but the problem is that all operators will be included in the final bundle.

Comment: If You use import 'rxjs'; yes but you should use import { operator} from 'rxjs/operators'

Comment: please check my update in the question. Nothing works fine.

Comment: @SandroSimas in your update you indicate you still have all kinds of other imports of rxjs in a `vendor.ts` file. You're also importing operators using the old (RxJS 5) way. This answer is in fact correct.

You should probably remove any reference to rxjs from your `vendor.ts` file and modify your imports throughout the application.

Answer (score 1):

You just need this two-part of code:

```
Import { filter, map } from "rxjs/operators"
```

In this list, you can add any operator that you need to use.

```
Import { Observable } from "rxjs"
```