# adding firebase to Ionic 3

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

**I'm trying to add firebase to ionic 3** but I'm getting an error on Object (...) not a function, everything runs well until the subscribe function gets executed then the error shows, I've done all needed integration and here my home.ts code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FirstPage } from '../first/first';
import { AskPage } from '../ask/ask';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
  public afd : AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.getDataFromFireBase();
  }

getDataFromFireBase(){
  this.afd.list('/Heros/').valueChanges().subscribe(
     data => {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
     }
  )
}
```

Comment: Please what am I doing wrong? thanks for your help.

Comment: The firebase is changed a lot for every version of ionic and angular.As far as i remember you need to use Observable in the ionic 3 version  (You need at least in the ionic 4+ angular 6 version)

Comment: thanks for the reply but i used an observable, .valueChanges().subscribe

Comment: Are you sure AngularFireDatabase import all you need ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376972/best-way-to-import-observable-from-rxjs