# Error in importing Observable from 'rxjs/Observable' in angular 4

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here is the error :-

> ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot
>   find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
>   src/app/services/data.service.ts(44,10): error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Users/Rupesh/Desktop/Projects/angulartest/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"'
>   has no exported member 'Observable'.

I have tried `npm install rxjs-compat/Observable` but still getting error. Help to fix this.

Comment: Look into your package.json and post your RxJs Version?

Comment: "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",

Answer (score 5):

You've to fix your Rxjs imports. There are some changes in the use of rxjs from v6 onwards. so, Kindly import the observable as below

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

instaed of `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

Answer (score 1):

install the whole rxjs-compact package

`npm install --save rxjs-compat`

Comment: I am getting the given below output :- ` npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ rxjs-compat@6.3.3
added 1 package and audited 38281 packages in 65.387s
found 12 vulnerabilities (9 low, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details `

Answer (score 1):

This is an old method.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

In angular 10 i have fixed this problem by using this method.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when I import Observable.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

until now, the only solution that i see is

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

But in another question from Stack, i read that way will increase the page load
([Best way to import Observable from rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376972/best-way-to-import-observable-from-rxjs))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following import : `import { Observable } from 'rxjs-compat/observable';`
rxjs has known some updates with time, and some syntaxes have changed. And in many cases, we now use use 'rxjs-compat', instead of 'rxjs'.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This looks to be a duplicate answer. Please edit if you want to add something new or else you can upvote another answer which you think is correct.

Comment: Duplicate Answer.