# Unable to import Observable in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rxjs

I install rxjs in my vue project. I am trying to import it like this

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
```

I am getting this error always

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs-compat/Observable'
```

If i use `import {Observable} from 'rxjs'` it is working fine.

rxjs version is

```
"rxjs": "^6.3.3"
```

How can i import only **Observable** inside rxjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 6, you have to use,

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'
```

In verison 5, you can directly import from `rxjs/Observalble`

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observalble'
```

Comment: Tried that still same issue.

Comment: If i import Observable from rxjs directly instead of rxjs/Observable, it will import every thing from rxjs even though i am using Observable.

Comment: Tried this one `import Observable from 'rxjs/Observable' ` still not working.

Comment: @Sam Above syntax will only work with version 5.In version 6 they changed it so you will have to use `import {Observable} from 'rxjs'`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376972/best-way-to-import-observable-from-rxjs)

Comment: its tough learning this stuff when they dont keep the tutorials up to date. Im looking at something on sitepoint and the rxjs stuff simply wont compile. still uses the http object.  oh well, if it was easy....